# Can Amplify Authentication SDK can be used on server side?

Tags: aws-amplify

I would like to use Amplify instead of amazon-cognito-identity-js in my lambda functions (to sync the cognito users with their profiles i store into another database).

On the client side everything works fine, but i am not able to use it on the server side.

I don't find any resources on the internet, and i am fighting since 2 hours trying to make it works, i start wondering if we are supposed to do that.

Does someone know how to configure Amplify by requiring only @aws-amplify/auth?

Auth.configure is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Amplify Auth is actually designed to work with the browser.  So it's not suitable for your lambda.

If you're using node then you will need to refer to the AWS SDK for JS instead.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @user1148920 Amplify is a client library. To sync your cognito users with DB, you need to use CognitoUser object returned by the Amplify `SignIn` and use it in API call to your backend to update the DB. You can use API Gateway endpoint to trigger lambda, that in turn does all kinda modificationss on the DynamoDB users table